Two stage differential amplifier as comparator
I used two stage differential opamp as comparator but I'm getting the output -ve voltage range.
I have to get high (1.8 V) when it is greater than reference voltage and low (0 V) when less than reference voltage. But as of now I'm getting high -6 V and low -1.75 V.
(net4 is reference voltage and net6 is the input voltage which is a sine wave.)
Schematic

vss=-1.8V , vdd-1.8V

Result


Can you ask a specific question?

You cannot get a -6 V outpput with only +/- 1.8 V power supplies.

I'm sorry but the sinus wave gets right up my nose... :-D

@TonyM Sorry, my bad

@Velvet, was nowhere near as bad as my line :-)

@TonyM On the contrary; it made me smile :)

From your schematic we cannot see what is "net6" that you use in the waveform plot, but I assume that it is V2, where the sine wave source is present. We can then further assume that "net4" is the reference voltage.
In the waveform plot the output is high when "net6" is higher than the reference voltage, and low when it is less than the reference voltage, which is exactly what you describe as the desired behavior in your question. So it is unclear why you are not satisfied!
Nevertheless, you can of course change the behavior to the opposite, by using the opposite input terminals for reference voltage and signal input. That is the essence of having a differential amplifier.
